# Django-ORM: Why is distinct() not working with annotations?

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm using `postgresql`:

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(articleinreports__report__in=reports_in_time_range).distinct().annotate(
            total_views=Case(
                    When(articleinreports__report=last_report,
                         then=(F("articleinreports__ios_views") + F("articleinreports__android_views")))
                , default=0, output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        ).order_by('-total_views')
```

Why is `distinct()` not getting applied and I'm getting two-articles instead of one for each unique article in the database?

Removing `order_by` does not solve (and that creates another problem anyway), only removing both the annotation and the `order_by`.

When I try to do `distinct('id')`, I get an error that it must match the `order_by` field, which defeats the purpose of ordering by my desired criteria.

Why is this happening, and how do I solve it for my use case?

Comment: Because ordering is done after the distinction filter. A database has a certain way to evaluate queries, you can see `ORDER BY` as an operation over a query with `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks. how then would I solve this? I want distinct articles, ordered by the `total_views` annotation..is this possible?

Comment: I think you probably should use a subquery here.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem haven’t used those until now. Care to elaborate?

Comment: But if I understand it correctly, you want for every `Article` the *maximum* number of `ios_views + android_views`. Why not simply use an extra filter. Can you perhaps first explain exactly *what* you want, instead of *how* you want to solve it?

Comment: I want to display ALL articles that have an ArticleInReport (which holds iOS_views + Android_views) associated with them in the last 24 hours. The number I want to display is the LATEST (in terms of time) number for these articles, OR 0 (if the Article doesn’t appear in the latest report, and therefore has no ArticleInReport associated that matches both the article and the report).